# React JSX elements doesn't inherit 'id' style properties

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have this component

```
// @flow
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import styles from './Counter.css';

class Counter extends Component {
    props: {
        activate: () => void,
        counter: number
    };

    render() {
        const { activate, counter } = this.props;
        return ( 
            <div className = { styles.container}>
            <div id="top-menu" className="ui secondary menu">
                <a className="active item">
                    Home
                </a>
                <a className="item">
                    Messages
                </a>
                <a className="item">
                    Friends
                </a>
                <div className="right menu">
                    <a className="ui item">
                    Logout
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type = "text" placeholder = "Enter activation key" className = {styles.input} /> 
            <button className = { styles.btn } onClick = { activate } > < i className = "btn"/>lala</button>  
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Counter;
```

As you can see the I import 'Counter.css' into the styles variable
and whenever I assign `className={styles.btn}` to some HTML element, it inherits the styles from 'Counter.css'. However, I have a rule for `#top-menu` in this css file which is not being assigned into this element. Is there any way to inherit id-defined rules from the css this way?

Comment: please post Counter.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using css modules in your build process. Which means that every css selector will get a suffix, and your `#top-menu` will become something like `#top-menu___3tSpk`. I don't think it's a recommend way to go, but if you really need it, than you can create global name like this `:global(#top-menu)`

Comment: I guess you're right.. I wasn't paying attention to the css loaders and thought this is some out of the box magic.. I'll try to get more comments about it and if not I'll give you the answer